# How do I write to a file in another directory using ofstream?

Tags: c++, io

I'm working on a project in C++.

In my current directory there is another folder, called game_files, and inside of game_files there is a file named player_name.txt

In my cpp file (Kingdom.cpp) I have the code below

```
std::string playerName; 
std::cin >> playerName;
std::ofstream nameFile;
nameFile.open("/game_files/player_name.txt")
nameFile << playerName;
nameFile.close();
```

Yet when I check the file, nothing has been written to it!
I have been searching for answers for a while and am completely lost.

Any and all help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You should check your stream with `fail` for starters. You are writing at the root of your system not in a subdir

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the leading slash from your filename. A leading slash indicates a full pathname, not a relative pathname.

Comment: Thanks so much, I didnt know that a leading slash meant it would be read as a full path name. This worked perfectly.

Comment: @Alice: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing) Read all of it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Alright.